# TextBlock MouseDown URL - How get my url in my code behind?

Tags: wpf, url, textblock, mousedown

I ve a list from sharepoint and i collect from this list an hyperlink. 
As i want my textbox to be like an hyperlink I ve added an event on mousedown to open this hyperlink, My concern is how to collect this hyperlink in the codebehind with the sender.
For the moment I've just hide this hyperlink in the tooltip maybe i can manage this differently any suggestion will be grantly appreciated.
My point so far, i don't know how to get this tooltip in the code behind.
Thanks

My XAML Code :

```
    <ListBox Name="ListboxTips" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Picture}"  Height="20"></Image>
                        <TextBlock MouseDown="TextBlock_MouseDown_URL" TextDecorations="Underline" 
                                   Margin="10,10,20,10" Width="160" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                                   Text="{Binding Path=TitleTip}" 
                                   ToolTip="{Binding Path=URL}"/>
                    </StackPanel>

                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

My code behind :

```
            foreach (SPSClient.ListItem item in TipsList)
            {

                var tips = new Tips();
                tips.TitleTip = item.FieldValues.Values.ElementAt(1).ToString();
                tips.App = item.FieldValues.Values.ElementAt(4).ToString();

                // get the Hyperlink field URL value 
                tips.URL = ((FieldUrlValue)(item["LinkDoc"])).Url.ToString();

                //should collect the description of the url
                //tips.URLdesc = ((FieldUrlValue)(item["LinkDoc"])).Description.ToString();
                tips.Picture = item.FieldValues.Values.ElementAt(4).ToString();

                colTips.Add(tips);
            }
            ListboxTips.DataContext = colTips;
```

....

```
    private void TextBlock_MouseDown_URL(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
    {
        //string test = (ToolTip)(sender as Control).ToString(); 
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.link.com");
        //System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(test); 
    }
```

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 0):

You can just access the property directly. It is not elegant, but will work!

```
private void TextBlock_MouseDown_URL(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
{
    TextBlock txtBlock = sender as TexBlock;
    // just access the property
    string url = txtBlock.ToolTip as string;
}
```

A more elegant approach might be to use a `Button`, `Hyperlink` or something that exposes a `Command`, so that you can bind the 'click' action to a command on your view model that performs the action you wish to execute.

Answer (score 0):

usually you stick any data you want to trespass somewhere to Tag attribute.

```
 <TextBlock .. Tag="{Binding Path=URL}" />
```

This is easily retrievable as a public property:

```
private void TextBlock_MouseDown_URL(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
{
    var tb = sender as TextBlock;
    if(tb != null) 
    {
       var neededUrl = tb.Tag;
    }
}
```